# Issue with defining and executing the function in Python

Tags: function, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Data which I am scraping using the beautiful soup contains one category of device name, device names contains `Colors` mentioned in them eg. Lumia 800 Black. I want to create a new column which contains this color.

I want to search the device name for any color against a list of colors & if color is present in that device name I want to remove that color from device name and put it in new column named Color.

I am using below referred code to accomplish this, I am creating a function named `color` and trying to search the device name string for presence of color and if present I am trying to feed that color to new variable named color_column. But my output csv is not returning any values at all. It is empty.

Please check the referred code below:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import urllib
import time
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice
colors = ["Black","Gray"]


def color(arg):
    for colors_1 in colors:
        if arg.find(colors_1) == -1:
            return color_column == ""
        return color_column == colors_1


url = 'http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/phones/default.aspx?shape=smartphones'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)'
values = {
'Phones':'MBBDevice',
'__ASYNCPOST':'true',
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
'__EVENTTARGET':'pgrTop$lnkPageShowAll',
'__LASTFOCUS':'',
'__VIEWSTATE':'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',
'ctl09':'ctl13|pgrTop$lnkPageShowAll',
'ddlSort':'0',
'hdnBlackBerryID':'3c2c3562-aa1c-4fe4-a0ca-da5dd8e4bd84',
'hdnCapCode':'',
'hdnDeviceId':'',
'hdnFeature':'',
'hdnFeatureNames':'',
'hdnFilter':'',
'hdnIsPricingOptionLockedB':'false',
'hdnLocationParameter':'',
'hdnManufacturer':'',
'hdnManufacturerID':'',
'hdnManufacturerNames':'',
'hdnOtherFilters':'',
'hdnPageIndex':'',
'hdnPriceRange':'',
'hdnPriceRangeText':'',
'hdnProductType':'GSM',
'hdnSelectedDeviceId':'',
'hdnSelections':'',
'hdnSortFilter':'0',
'hdnTitle':'',
'hdnType':'smp,',
'hdnTypeNames':'Smartphone|',
'popupPlanChangeRequired$hdnDeviceID':'',
'popupPlanChangeRequired$hdnFamilyID':'',
'popupPlanChangeRequired$hiddenImagePath':'',
'repTypes$ctl05$chkType':'on',
'txtSelectedDevices':'0',
'txtSelectedFeatures':'0'}
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

with open('tmob_colortest.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "phonename"}, text = colors)
    prices = soup.findAll('p', {"class": "totalitemprice"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(islice(item.stripped_strings, 0, 2, 1))
        textcontent2 = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        name_1 = unicode(textcontent).encode('utf8').replace('Nexus 4','LG Nexus 4').replace(' T-Mobile Refurbished Device','').replace('â„¢','').replace('Â®','').replace(' Â›','').replace("NEW! ","").replace(" Web-only offer -- now thru Thu 1/3/13","").replace(" Web-only offer!","").strip()
        oem = list(name_1)
        pos = oem.index(' ')
        if name_1.find('Refurbished')== -1:
            name= name_1
            refur = "N"
        else:
            name = name_1.replace("Refurbished","").replace(" -","")
            refur = "Y"        
        spamwriter.writerow(["US", "T-Mobile",
                             name[0:pos],name,refur,color_column,
                             "24 Months","$",unicode(textcontent2).encode('utf8').replace("FREE","0").replace('$','')])
```

Please help me to solve this issue and pardon my ignorance as I am new to coding.

Comment: You seem to open and immediately close the `csv` file there; is your indentation correct? As soon as the `with` block is done (the line starting with `items`) the file is closed again.

Comment: ohh, its wrong here but in my code it is correct. Error in Pasting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you please help me with this? Instead of using function I tried using "for loop" also directly in the `with` section `for color in colors:
            if name.find(color) == -1:
                color_column = color
            else:
                color_column = "" ` this is returning only "Gray" value for rows where gray is not present while empty for rows where is it present

Comment: I can help later when I have some time; a little busy at the moment, sorry!

Comment: No Problem, but please do look into it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually use your function, so `color_column` is never filled.

What you want to do is make your function return the changed product name, and the color detected, as two separate values:

```
def handle_color(arg):
    for col in colors:
        if col.lower() not in arg.lower():
            continue
        # color found, remove it from arg (case insensitively)
        start = arg.lower().index(col.lower())
        arg = arg[:start] + arg[start + len(col):]
        return arg, col
    # No matching color found, return arg unchanged and an empty value for the color
    return arg, ''
```

Now all you have to do is call this function and unpack it's return value into two variables for your CSV:

```
    name, color_column = handle_color(name)
```

and `color_column` will either be an empty value or the matched color (now removed from `name`).